# Excel INDEX/MATCH but the columns aren't always in the same place

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got data coming to me in spreadsheets where the columns aren't always in the same place. I found some code to reorder the columns according to an array in VBA but every time I shift them around it moves all the references, like I want to refer to column 1 but I put column 1 in column 3 and all the formulas in the worksheet followed that change to column 3. I think you can find my question about that in my history.

So now I have a table with lots of columns, and two of those columns are **one_unknown** and **two_unknown**, and they could be anywhere on the sheet. I want to find the value of *x* which is in the **one_unknown** column, that has the same row number as value *y* in the **two_unknown** column. I end up with a bunch of tangled formulas with INDEX and MATCH, starting with

```
MATCH("two_unknown",1:1)
```

to get the column number of **two_unknown**, and the same process to get the column number of **one_unknown**.

But then I want to use INDEX and tell it to look for *y* in **two_unknown** but all I have is a number, not a range, say if it's in column 4 I have a LONG variable 4 and I want a RANGE variable D:D.

I started writing a function to turn a numeric value into the range defined by that column's number and it just seemed so silly. Every other solution I think of is just as inelegant and mangled and I feel like I've been staring at it too long when the solution is probably way simpler than I think.

Anyone know what I should do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show some sample data?

Comment: Try to use `range.offset()` with your column number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with a number of formula approaches.

How about turning the data into an Excel Table? Ensure the names of the columns are what you expect. In this formula, the lookup value is in a column called LookHere and the result column is called ReturnThis, then you can use

```
=INDEX(Table1[ReturnThis],MATCH(I2,Table1[LookHere],0))
```

Or if you have Office 365, use the new XLookup

```
=XLOOKUP(K2,Table1[LookHere],Table1[ReturnThis])
```

If, for some reason, you can't turn the data into an Excel table, you can use MATCH to return the position of the columns for example like this, assuming the column labels are in row 1:

```
=MATCH("LookHere",1:1,0)
=MATCH("ReturnThis",1:1,0)
```

Put these into worksheet cells, like cells K4 and K5 and then use an Index / Match like this, building an index with two INDEX formulas turned into a range with the intersection ":" operator. You will need to provide row numbers for first and last row for this approach.

```
=INDEX(INDEX(A:F,1,K5):INDEX(A:F,100,K5),MATCH(K2,INDEX(A:F,1,K4):INDEX(A:F,100,K4),0))
```

[image]

OR

set up named ranges with these formulas and use the named ranges
=INDEX(INDEX(A:F,1,ReturnThisColumn):INDEX(A:F,100,ReturnThisColumn),MATCH(K2,INDEX(A:F,1,LookHereColumn):INDEX(A:F,100,LookHereColumn),0))

OR

If you have the new Let() function, you can use that instead of named ranges.

Comment: My goodness, it's true that the very simple answer was staring me in the face. I don't know why I didn't see that turning it into a table would allow me to refer to those columns by their names. In fact, this is the most sensible thing to do with all the other data I'm importing as well. I'll use VBA to turn the imports into tables. Thank you @teylyn!

Comment: And the LET() function looks very useful as well, thanks. New to me