# Deleting and recreating a table without losing references

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This question is a follow-up to an earlier one on here ([Excel INDEX/MATCH but the columns aren't always in the same place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62707282/excel-index-match-but-the-columns-arent-always-in-the-same-place)) where I learned it was so much easier to find values using INDEX and MATCH on my datasheet if I turned it into a table and referred to the columns by their field names.

As I mentioned in that question, I've got data coming to me with the columns in different orders. I'm building a template so that users can import their own data and all the references on all the other sheets will just fill up.

The problem now is that I have a function that clears the data before importing the next set, and when it does that, all the references to the table (i.e. Table_Name[field_name]) are gone, and they say #REF! even though the table is now there (having been deleted and recreated in the same spot).

How do I stop this from happening? It's no better than what was happening before, i.e. the references to columns moving automatically throughout the sheet when those columns were re-ordered.

Anyone know what to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you deleting the table if all you need to do is clear the data?

Comment: Because I never know what order the next table's columns will be in

Comment: I suggest you change your import routine, so that it either creates a new table with the proper headings; or that it imports just the data and figures out which column to stick it based on matching the incoming headings with your list of headings.

Comment: column order should not matter. You can change the heading name of the list object and the data straight in VBA

Comment: I may be searching the wrong terms but i literally can't find anything showing me how to automate an import to an already existing table., potentially adding or skipping fields (columns) along the way

Comment: Might help to show your existing code.